Is it possible to remove (0,...) expression from Webpack generated code?
Webpack will generate this code
import { useState } from 'react';

useState(0);

into this code
(0,react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useState)(0);
// which can be later minified into this code
// (0,a.b)(0);

I have hundreds of imports in my application and each time Webpack adds 4 extra symbols. I know that Webpack tries to make 'this' equal to 'undefined' this way. All the libraries I use don't use 'this' keyword in the exported functions.
// Is it possible to make webpack generate this code
react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useState(0);
// instead of this?
(0,react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useState)(0);


Looks like something you could tackle with a well placed 'replace' and regular expression? Is it worth it?
